# How to add submodules, frameworks or libraries to SVN repository

Tags: ios, xcode, svn

I'm creating a new iOS project were I would like to use some integration libraries. I.E: facebook, sharekit, etc. I noticed most of them come as static libraries or git submodules... so the question is how would you upload those libraries into an SVN repository??. I mean it would be great for any developer to just download the svn repo content and run the app. So basically I would like to configure the project in such a way that all libraries or frameworks are linked relative to base folder maybe? And then upload all of that content. What are the recommended ways of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

I typically just grab the resources I need, put them where I want them in my directory hierarchy locally (inside a checked-out SVN project) and then add/commit them to my repo.  Certainly no harm in doing so.  If you're looking for dynamic resource loading (a la `maven` for example) you'll need to go a different route, but it sounds to me like you're not.

As a side note, if you're starting a fresh iOS app and plan to integrate with a bunch of third party APIs, you might want to take a look at [Temboo's SDK for iOS](https://www.temboo.com/download) *(full disclosure: I work at Temboo)*.  It greatly simplifies integrating with APIs, and with OAuth headaches in general.  The SDK is free to use and currently supports 100+ APIs, you can see which ones (and try them out) [here](https://live.temboo.com/library/).

Cheers